# Implementing Stop and wait with C & UDP, and what does cause 'resource temporarily unavailable'?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recvfrom

I am implementing stop&wait with c and udp socket programming. To simulate this protocol, I wrote two codes.

This is my `server.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


typedef struct packet{
    char data[1024];
}Packet;

typedef struct frame{
    int frame_kind; //ACK:0, SEQ:1 FIN:2
    int sq_no;
    int ack;
    Packet packet;
}Frame;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int sockfd;
    int clilen;
    int state;
    int n;
    int sum;
    int recv_result;

    int frame_id = 0;

    Packet packet;
    Frame frame;
    Frame recv_frame;
    char buffer[1024] = "";

    struct timeval tv;

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;

    FILE* infile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        perror("error! usage: $./server <PORT> filename\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(infile == NULL)
    {
        printf("error! failed to open the file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    clilen = sizeof(clientaddr);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); //using diagram instead of stream-- UDP
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket error: ");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero(&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1])); //set port number 9999

    //set socket option -- timeout is 100000 microseconds

    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));

    state = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    if(state == -1)
    {
        perror("bind error: ");
        exit(0);
    }

    do{
        n = fscanf(infile, "%s", buffer);

        strcpy(packet.data, buffer);
        memcpy(&(frame.packet), &packet, sizeof(Packet));
        frame.frame_kind = 1; //SEQ
        frame.sq_no = frame_id;
        frame.ack = 0;
        printf("flag2");
        while(1)
        {
            sendto(sockfd, &frame, sizeof(frame), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, (socklen_t)clilen);
            printf("Frame %d sent\n", frame_id);
            recv_result = recvfrom(sockfd, &recv_frame, sizeof(recv_frame), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &clilen );

            if(recv_result > 0 && recv_frame.sq_no == 0 && recv_frame.ack == frame_id){
                printf("Ack %d received\n", recv_frame.sq_no);
                break;
            }else{
                printf("Frame %d time expired\n", frame_id);
            }
        }
        frame_id++;
    }while(n > 0);

    printf("finished\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my `client.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

typedef struct packet{
    char data[1024];
}Packet;

typedef struct frame{
    int frame_kind; //ACK:0, SEQ:1 FIN:2
    int sq_no;
    int ack;
    Packet packet;
}Frame;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    int str_len;
    socklen_t adr_sz;
    FILE* outfile = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    struct sockaddr_in serv_adr, from_adr;
    Frame ackframe, recv_frame;
    int frame_id;
    int recv_result;
    struct timeval tv;

    if(argc!=3){
        printf("Usage : %s <IP> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    sock=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);   
    if(sock==-1)
    {
        printf("error! failed to open the socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&serv_adr, 0, sizeof(serv_adr));
    adr_sz = sizeof(serv_adr);
    serv_adr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_adr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    serv_adr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));

    frame_id = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        recv_result = recvfrom(sock, &recv_frame, sizeof(recv_frame), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_adr, &adr_sz);
        perror("error: ");
        printf("data %s\n", recv_frame.packet.data);
        printf("recv result %d\n", recv_result);
        printf("recv frame=%d, frame_kind = %d\n", recv_frame.sq_no, recv_frame.frame_kind);
        if(recv_result > 0 && recv_frame.frame_kind == 1 && recv_frame.sq_no==frame_id){
            printf("Frame %d received\n", recv_frame.sq_no);
            fprintf(outfile, "%s", recv_frame.packet.data);
            ackframe.frame_kind = 0;
            ackframe.ack = recv_frame.sq_no + 1;
            printf("Ack %d sent\n", ackframe.ack);
            sendto(sock, &recv_frame, sizeof(recv_frame), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_adr, adr_sz);


            break;
        }else{
            printf("Frame %d time expired\n", frame_id);
        }
    }   
    close(sock);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

The server needs 3 arguments: `./server <port> <test.txt>`

The client needs also 3 arguments: `./client <ip> <port>`

It is executed, but `recvfrom` of client always returns `-1`.

I read some questions with same topic, but could not find out the error from my code. Is there any way to fix my code with `recvfrom` & `sendto`? Or do I need to use `select` function? (I will only communicate with one server & one client.)

Comment: You *do* realize that `fread()` doesn't null-terminate what it reads?

Comment: Oh I fixed it in my newest code, but did not fix the one of this code. But I don't think it is the reason of 'resource temporarily unavailable' error.

Comment: Given that you `strcpy()` something that is possibly not null-terminated, and right afterwards you `memcpy()` that same content, I am not inclined to debug this code for you.

Comment: If a system-call like [`recvfrom`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html) return `-1` then you can (and should) check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see what went wrong. Also, the value of `errno` is *undefined* if the previous function didn't actually failed, never check `errno` unless the previous function actually failed.

Comment: The result of perror is "Resource temporarily Unavailable". I read another question and according to it, it is because there is no data to read from the socket. I wonder is there any solution to solve this problem with using recvfrom function.

Comment: Also, this error has a name EAGAIN.

Comment: You get that error because you might have set a to low timeout. If there's nothing to receive then the `recvfrom` function will timeout and return that error. As for *why* there's nothing received is a different story altogether, and there may be a hundred different reasons for it, but after a quick glance at your code it seems that your programs are a little off, I'll explain more in an answer.

Comment: @jungyh0218 Could you provide the working code in the answer. I am facing the same issue and not able to resolve it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you provide the working code in the answer. I am facing the same issue and not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "client" and "server" program contains some dubious code. First lets take the "server", which calls `sendto` with `clientaddr` which you ***haven't initialized***. Who knows where you try to send the packets. This, in fact, leads to *undefined behavior*, as the contents of the structure is *indeterminate*.

Then lets take the client, in which you call `recvfrom` on a socket that isn't bound locally. The address structure pointer you pass to `recvfrom` is filled in by the `recvfrom` function, but the data in it is not used in any other way.

There are probably other problems, but these two stand out.

Comment: I fixed it. The cause was initialization.  :)

Comment: @jungyh0218 please add working code in the answer I am facing the same issue. I am a beginner

Comment: @Iamlearning If you look at the server code in the question, you see that the OP is initializing the structure `serveraddr`, but not the structure `clientaddr`. You must initialize the address structure with the address you want to send the packet to.